# how to check scroll bottom and top

Tags: android, onscrolllistener, onscrollchanged

bellow source code is not perfect code.

work to one side, work to only bottom side.

how to edit?

please give me edit example.

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }

        int mPosition=0;
        int mOffset=0;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int position = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                View v = list.getChildAt(0);
                int offset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

                 if (mPosition < position || (mPosition == position && mOffset < offset)){
                      // Scrolled up 

                 } else {
                      // Scrolled down

                }
        }
     });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114963/detecting-the-scrolling-direction-in-the-adapter-up-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP); and scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);