# How can I set visibily gone on scrolling downwards?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I have kept a button in my scroll view which should be visible only when I am scrolling up and should get invisible as I scroll down like in paytm. It is a simple scroll view inside a fragment.

```
      scrollBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            scroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });

    scrollBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    });
```

---

Comment: Hello if you need some help you should provide some code. Anyway you should handle the scroll event of the scroll view and hide or show the button depending the scroll direction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview

Comment: @JuanjoBerenguer yehh.. added the code.. inintially I have kept the visibillity of scroll btn gone..

Comment: Hello Surbhi, could you add your layout file?

Comment: @SurbhiKartpay check my answer hope this help you. if it's helpful then pls do mark as a right tickmark. happy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you.

**Code**

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onScrollChange(View view, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
               //Scrolling down
               if(scrollY<oldScrollY){
                   scrollBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }else{
                   scrollBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
           }
       });
```

Comment: Its working.. but if I keep on scrolling even when I reached top the button gets visible...

Comment: Thank you.. I just have to make make the visibility of scrollbtn  GONE, after its onClick...

Comment: Hello. I am glad to know that! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

check out this one [Detecting the scrolling direction in the adapter (up/down)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114963/detecting-the-scrolling-direction-in-the-adapter-up-down) and inside `mIsScrollingUp = false;`

use your code to hide the layout u need

Comment: Can you please tell me where to add this line of code?