# Hide FloatingActionButton on scroll of RecyclerView

Tags: scroll, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to hide/show `FloatingActionButton` on scroll of `RecyclerView`.

My `XML` layout :

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_eventlist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_createevent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerview_eventlist"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                app:layout_behavior="com.eventizon.behavior.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/custom_color_1"
                app:borderWidth="0dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

DrawerLayout is the parent layout of this layout.

```
    public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {


    private static final String TAG = "ScrollAwareFABBehavior";

    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
        Log.e(TAG,"ScrollAwareFABBehavior");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
            FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed,
            int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed,
                dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        Log.e(TAG,"onNestedScroll called");
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            Log.e(TAG,"child.hide()");
            child.hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            Log.e(TAG,"child.show()");
            child.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Used this layout behaviour for `FloatingActionButton`.

When I see `logcat` only constructor is getting called. `onNestedScroll()` doesn't get called when I scroll the list.

Comment: anyone got the solution for it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, here is what you need:

First, since your FAB depends on the `RecyclerView`, add the following to your behavior class:

```java
@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
    if(dependency instanceof RecyclerView)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Next, in order to receive `onNestedScroll()` calls, you need to override this:

```java
 public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {

    //predict whether you will need to react to the RecyclerView's scroll;
    //if yes, return true, otherwise return false to avoid future calls
    //of onNestedScroll()
    return true;
}
```

Good luck!

**Update**

Here is what your `ScrollAwareFABBehavior` should look like:

```java
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
    private static final String TAG = "ScrollAwareFABBehavior";

    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
        if(dependency instanceof RecyclerView)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                               FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed,
                               int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed,
                dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {    
            child.hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            child.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, it was tested using `com.android.support:design:23.0.1`

Comment: still didn't work. Is it because my support library is outdated?

Comment: can you provide me with a working example if possible?

Comment: @Pritam Kadam have a  look at my updated answer for a complete solution.

Comment: our ScrollAwareFABBehavior looks exactly the same but it is still not working and version of my support library is 23.1

Comment: Your issue must be somewhere else perhaps the DrawerLayout

Comment: I will test it later with DrawerLayout and see what the problem is.

Comment: I tested it with a DrawerLayout and everything works, the only thing I can do now is look at more of your code. Other than that I can't really help. Sorry.

Comment: 1. `layoutDependsOn` is unnecessary. You only need to capture scroll event, not layout events. 2. Maybe you need to consider `dyUnconsumed` in `onNestedScroll`?

Comment: That is a great answer and should be correct one! thanks :)

Answer (score 114):

Easiest solution:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
    {
        if (dy > 0 ||dy<0 && fab.isShown())
        {
            fab.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
    {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
        {
            fab.show();
        }

        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried with codepath guide but I have lost some time. This is easiest one

Comment: This hide FAB when scrolling.but when you stop scroll fab showed. How can hide it when scroll down and it hide until you scroll up?

Comment: This seems to hide while scrolling but if you flight it hides and reappears twice

Answer (score 44):

This should work for you:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx,int dy){
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        if (dy >0) {
            // Scroll Down
            if (fab.isShown()) {
                fab.hide();
            }
        }
        else if (dy <0) {
            // Scroll Up
            if (!fab.isShown()) {
                fab.show();
            }
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Good solution, thanks

Answer (score 15):

**Short and Simple Solution:**

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (dy > 0 && mFloatingActionButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mFloatingActionButton.hide();
        } else if (dy < 0 && mFloatingActionButton.getVisibility() !=View.VISIBLE) {
            mFloatingActionButton.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @PriyaRajan glade it helped you :)

Answer (score 14):

If you are using [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)  and your FAB is inside a CoordinatorLayout then you can use the `layout_behavior` `com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior`

```xml
   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/filter_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ...
            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior" 
            ... />
```

Comment: This is good but keep in mind this will overlap with you snackbar if you don't anchor your snackbar to your fab.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using coordinator layout and want to hide and show FAB smoothly. And you want to implement your own logic to hide fab on scroll down, and show it on scrolling up.

Then here is the solution in kotlin,

- Declare a variable,

```
var scrollingDown = false
```

- After that create a listener,

```
recycler_view_id.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

                if (scrollingDown && dy >= 0) {
                    scrollingDown = !scrollingDown
                    id_show_media_fab.startAnimation(
                        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            R.anim.fab_close
                        )
                    )
                } else if (!scrollingDown && dy < 0) {
                    scrollingDown = !scrollingDown
                    id_show_media_fab.startAnimation(
                        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            R.anim.fab_open
                        )
                    )
                }

            }
        })
```

- create anim resource file

fab_open.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="100%"
        android:toXScale="0.9"
        android:toYScale="0.9" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

fab_close.xml

```
just change 

android:fromXScale="0.8"
android:fromYScale="0.8"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did. It works for me! If you don't know how to implement, You can see detail in this link https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons

```
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            child.hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            child.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a ***custom RecyclerView*** which has **`OnUpDownScrollListener`**, **`OnLeftRightScrollListener`** ready:

#### Code:

**MBRecyclerView.java**

```
public class MBRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private OnScrollListener wrappedUpDownScrollListener;
    private OnScrollListener wrappedLeftRightScrollListener;

    public MBRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MBRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MBRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
    }

    // region Scrolling Listener for Up, Down, Left and Right
    public void setOnUpDownScrollListener(final OnUpDownScrollListener onUpDownScrollListener) {
        if (wrappedUpDownScrollListener == null) {
            wrappedUpDownScrollListener = getWrappedUpDownScrollListener(onUpDownScrollListener);
            addOnScrollListener(wrappedUpDownScrollListener);
        }
    }

    public void removeOnUpDownScrollListener() {
        if (wrappedUpDownScrollListener != null) {
            removeOnScrollListener(wrappedUpDownScrollListener);
            wrappedUpDownScrollListener = null;
        }
    }

    public void setLeftOnRightScrollListener(final OnLeftRightScrollListener onLeftRightScrollListener) {
        if (wrappedLeftRightScrollListener == null) {
            wrappedLeftRightScrollListener = getWrappedLeftRightScrollListener(onLeftRightScrollListener);
            addOnScrollListener(wrappedLeftRightScrollListener);
        }
    }

    public void removeOnLeftRightScrollListener() {
        if (wrappedLeftRightScrollListener != null) {
            removeOnScrollListener(wrappedLeftRightScrollListener);
            wrappedLeftRightScrollListener = null;
        }
    }

    private OnScrollListener getWrappedUpDownScrollListener(final OnUpDownScrollListener onUpDownScrollListener) {
        return new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (onUpDownScrollListener != null) {
                    // Negative to check scrolling up, positive to check scrolling down
                    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
                        onUpDownScrollListener.onScrolledToTop();
                    } else if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                        onUpDownScrollListener.onScrolledToBottom();
                    }
                    if (dy > 0) {
                        onUpDownScrollListener.onScrollDown(dy);
                    } else if (dy < 0) {
                        onUpDownScrollListener.onScrollUp(dy);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (onUpDownScrollListener != null) {
                        onUpDownScrollListener.onScrollStopped();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private OnScrollListener getWrappedLeftRightScrollListener(final OnLeftRightScrollListener onLeftRightScrollListener) {
        return new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (onLeftRightScrollListener != null) {
                    // Negative to check scrolling left, positive to check scrolling right
                    if (!recyclerView.canScrollHorizontally(-1)) {
                        onLeftRightScrollListener.onScrolledToMostLeft();
                    } else if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                        onLeftRightScrollListener.onScrolledToMostRight();
                    }
                    if (dy > 0) {
                        onLeftRightScrollListener.onScrollRight(dx);
                    } else if (dy < 0) {
                        onLeftRightScrollListener.onScrollLeft(dx);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (onLeftRightScrollListener != null) {
                        onLeftRightScrollListener.onScrollStopped();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public abstract class OnUpDownScrollListener {
        public void onScrollUp(int dy) {}

        public void onScrollDown(int dy) {}

        public void onScrolledToTop() {}

        public void onScrolledToBottom() {}

        public void onScrollStopped() {}
    }

    public abstract class OnLeftRightScrollListener {
        public void onScrollLeft(int dx) {}

        public void onScrollRight(int dx) {}

        public void onScrolledToMostRight() {}

        public void onScrolledToMostLeft() {}

        public void onScrollStopped() {}
    }
    // endregion
}
```

#### Usage (UpDownScrollListener):

```
    mbRecyclerView.setOnUpDownScrollListener(new MBRecyclerView.OnUpDownScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollUp(int dy) {
            // show
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollDown(int dy) {
            // hide
        }

        // aditional functions:
        public void onScrolledToTop() {}
        public void onScrolledToBottom() {}
        public void onScrollStopped() {}
    });
```

similarely you can handle the LeftRight scrolling by setting

```
setOnLeftRightScrollListener
```

I hope it can help somebody :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in: [F.A.B Hides but Doesn't Show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414531/f-a-b-hides-but-doesnt-show/47994765#47994765)

The problem is Android 25.0.x+ sets the view to GONE and thats why the listener is not reporting changes.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers which goes on the Behavior path and onNestedScroll (instead of recyclerview listener) don't comment about the fact that onNestedScroll will be called many times while scrolling. This means that child.show() and child.hide() will be called many times as well. Although show() and hide() are designed to handle that scenario, they still run a lot of code and create some objects which multiplied by the times onNestedScroll is called, result in a lot of objects created unnecessarily.

Considering that and because I wanted to run a different animation instead of the default show() and hide(), I came up with the following Behavior implementation:

```java
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton>  {

private static final String TAG = "ScrollAwareFABBehavior";

private boolean fabAnimationStarted = false;
private boolean flingHappened = false;

public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target, int axes, int type) {

    if (target instanceof RecyclerView) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull final FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View target, int type) {
    super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, type);

    // If animation didn't start, we don't need to care about running the restore animation.
    // i.e.: when the user swipes to another tab in a viewpager. The onNestedPreScroll is never called.
    if (!fabAnimationStarted) {
        return;
    }

    // Animate back when the fling ended (TYPE_NON_TOUCH)
    // or if the user made the touch up (TYPE_TOUCH) but the fling didn't happen.
    if (type == ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH || (type == ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH && !flingHappened)) {
        ViewCompat.animate(child).translationY(0).start();

        fabAnimationStarted = false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNestedFling(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {

    // We got a fling. Flag it.
    flingHappened = true;
    return false;

}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View target, int dx, int dy, @NonNull int[] consumed, int type) {

    if (!fabAnimationStarted) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartNestedScroll: animation is starting");
        fabAnimationStarted = true;
        flingHappened = false;
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        ViewCompat.animate(child).translationY(child.getHeight() + lp.bottomMargin).start();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The floating action button will hide when there's scrolling and show when the scrolling stops.

```
  recylerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    switch (newState) {
                        case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                            addExpenseBtn.show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            addExpenseBtn.hide();
                            break;
                    }
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

//lv = ListView

```
    lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            fab.setVisibility(view.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: When giving answers is always nice to add some explanation and not just post a raw snippet without any info.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in a RecyclerView.Adapter's onBindViewHolder method to set the bottom margin of the last item in the list to 72dp so that it will scroll up above the floating action button.

This does not require a dummy entry in the list.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // other binding code goes here.

    if (position + 1 == getItemCount()) {
        // set bottom margin to 72dp.
        setBottomMargin(holder.itemView, (int) (72 * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    } else {
        // reset bottom margin back to zero. (your value may be different)
        setBottomMargin(holder.itemView, 0);
    }
}

public static void setBottomMargin(View view, int bottomMargin) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(params.leftMargin, params.topMargin, params.rightMargin, bottomMargin);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but it works for me.

```
//This only works on Android M and above
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        if (scrollY > oldScrollY && fab.isShown()) {
            fab.hide();
        } else if (scrollY < oldScrollY && !fab.isShown()) {
            fab.show();
        }
    }
});
```

When `scrollY` is greater than `oldScrollY`, that means user has scroll down so, we just need to check FAB is showing. If it is, we hide it.

`scrollY` is less than `oldScrollY` means a scroll up. We check if FAB is still hidden to show it.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                //Customize your if statement  
                if (recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset() > recyclerView.getHeight() * 2) {
                    if (!fab.isShown()) {
                        fab.show();
                    }
                } else {
                    fab.hide();
                }
            }
        });
```

enjoy.