# Hide floating action button after recyclerview is scrolled in Viewpager fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, floating-action-button

I have a viewpager in the containerActivity hosting two fragments, both having recyclerview, The floating action button is in the container activity, I want to hide fab on recyclerview scrolling.

This StackOverFlow post has the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208613/hide-floatingactionbutton-on-scroll-of-recyclerview)

But the problem is how to notify the fab in container activity that the recyclerview in the fragment is scrolled.

I am new to android, So any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: use custom listener interface

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617398/floatingactionbutton-hide-on-list-scroll

Comment: @Divyesh Can you show me a code snippet on how to create custom listener interface or if pointing to a good tutorial on how to create custom listener interface is also fine, as I said I am new to android programming. Thanks!

Comment: @Keyur The solution in the post works unfortunately :(

Comment: http://techblogon.com/communication-between-activity-and-fragment-example/

Comment: @Haaris Ahamed Upvote each answer and comment which is useful, so that it can help other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this method.
it worked for me

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    if (dy > 0 && mFloatingActionButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        mFloatingActionButton.hide();
    } else if (dy < 0 && mFloatingActionButton.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        mFloatingActionButton.show();
    }
}});
```