# how to Hide the floating action button/menu while scrolling inside a coordinator layout

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, android-nestedscrollview

i want to hide my `FloatingActionMenu` when there's a scrolling inside my nested scroll view.
i'm using a 3rd party library for an action menu , [Clans-FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)
i found out a class for `layout_behavior` , but the most of the methods are `Deprecated`
Here's the class :

```
public class FabMenuBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionMenu> {

private int accumulator = 0;
private int threshold = 0;

public FabMenuBehavior() {
    super();
}

public FabMenuBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionMenu child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    threshold = (child.getChildCount() > 0 ? child.getChildAt(0).getHeight() : child.getHeight()) / 2;
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionMenu child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
    if ((accumulator * dyConsumed) < 0) { //scroll direction change
        accumulator = 0;
    }
    accumulator += dyConsumed;

    if (accumulator > threshold && !child.isMenuButtonHidden()) {
        child.hideMenuButton(true);
    } else if (accumulator < -threshold && child.isMenuButtonHidden()) {
        child.showMenuButton(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionMenu child, View target) {
    super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target);
    accumulator = 0;
}

}
```

So how can achieve that ? thank you.

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: Unfortunately It's Deprecated

Comment: You can still use deprecated methods until they are removed. Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208613/hide-floatingactionbutton-on-scroll-of-recyclerview

Comment: I know , this class works perfectly.. But i don't want to have any troubles later when the methods get removed

Comment: If you clicked into the deprecated classes/methods do they tell you which classes/methods are recommended to use instead?

Comment: thats what it says : 
Overrides deprecated method in 'android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.Behavior' less... 
This inspection reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope