# Hide Floating Action Button in Android unless position in Recycler View is at the very top

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, material-design, floating-action-button

I'm trying to only display a floating action button when the Recycler View position is at the very top. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Here is my current layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#BBB"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/postsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_post" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617398/floatingactionbutton-hide-on-list-scroll.

Comment: I tried using that already but I believe it's different when using a recycler view instead of the list view

Comment: Try this: https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/

Comment: Thanks Daniel that worked