# android ViewPager with Floating Button and listView

Tags: android, listview, floating-action-button

hi i have an **ViewPager** and **FloatingButton** on my main activity and view pager have some **Fragments** with ListView i want to know is there any way when my lists on viewpager scroll this FloatingButton Hide and show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

We will add a function in main activity that will get called from fragment, the function will hide/show the floating action button.

**In MainActivity**

```
//Make FAB accessible on all function, declare it in MainActivity's class
FloatingActionButton fab;

public void fabShowHide(Boolean hide){
     if(hide)
         fab.hide();
     else
         fab.show();
}
```

**In your fragment, attach onScrollListner to your listview**

Replace **YourActivityClassName** with the main activity class name, this is probably **MainActivity**, check the name of the class in main activity

```
 listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if (lastItem == totalItemCount && firstVisibleItem > 0) {
        //Calling the function from main activity (hide)
            ((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).fabShowHide(true);
        }
        else {
        //Calling the function from main activity (show)
            ((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).fabShowHide(false);
        }
    }
});
```

**Floating Action Button in Main Activity**

(Delete the app behavior, you don't need it, we created it programmly)

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Good luck :)

Sources:

[Call an activity method from a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659747/call-an-activity-method-from-a-fragment)

[FloatingActionButton hide on list scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617398/floatingactionbutton-hide-on-list-scroll)

Comment: i search a bit is there any way can i use scrollawarefabbehavior on this? or maybe a good animation i do only fab.setVisibilty(GONE) and for show like this

Comment: Hi there, if you use my method it will do a nice hide/show animation - when using FAB's method fab.show() or fab.hide() it will do a nice reveal animation.