# Listview download content at end of the list

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a populated ListView with custom adapter and my objective is to download new content when user scrolls to the end of it ? How to achieve it ? I think it should be something in here :

```
        mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

but I don't know what exactly to put there.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358428/implementation-of-onscrolllistener-to-detect-the-end-of-scrolling-in-a-listview) . What I would recommend is putting this in your onScroll :

```
if (++firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount > totalItemCount) {
    // do whatever you want here

}
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check CommonsWare's Endless Adapter? Check [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) out. It might solve your problem.