# How to know when my listview reaches its bottom

Tags: android, android-listview

So, I have this listview that I keep feeding information from a database. Everytime I reach the bottom of the list, I load X more itens from the database. I know when I reach the bottom by doing this

> total - 1 = count;

Where total is the total number of visible itens (totalItemCount) on the listview and count is visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem.

This works just fine when my device is on landscape, but, when I change the orientation to portrait the visibleItemCount and the TotalItemCount change and the my test goes to hell and my listview goes crazy loading a bunch of nulls and eventually crashing.

SO, what I want to know: Is there a way to know when my listview reached its bottom ? Independent of the devices orientation.

Comment: you might want to try this endless list by commonsware https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Comment: I'm already using a few libs (like slidingmenu and pulltorefresh), so I'm trying to avoid using libs for things that I can do. But, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onScrollListener` to detect the end of scrolling. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358428/implementation-of-onscrolllistener-to-detect-the-end-of-scrolling-in-a-listview).

Comment: The problem was that when I changed the screen orientation, the number of visible items increased (Because the whole listview was visible). With this behavior the listview loaded more items. So, what I did was actually lower the layout_height of the my activity so fewer rows would be visible at a portrait orientation. I was already using something like link you provided, but reading it helped me realize my mistake. Many thanks.