# Find out if ListView is scrolled to the up?

Tags: android

whit this below action i can check scrolling list view down is finish. now i want to check list view scrolling to up and finish. how to get this event?

```
@Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (prevVisibleItem != firstVisibleItem) {
            if (prevVisibleItem < firstVisibleItem)
                Log.e(getClass().toString(), "DOWN");
            else
                Log.e(getClass().toString(), "UP");

            prevVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            /*
            * CHECK SCROLLING BUTTOM FINISH
            */

            if((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) ==  totalItemCount)
            {
                Log.i("Info", "Scroll Bottom FINISH" );
            }

            /*
            * CHECK SCROLLING UP FINISH
            */
        }
    }
```

Comment: That might be helpful...[CLICKHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358428/implementation-of-onscrolllistener-to-detect-the-end-of-scrolling-in-a-listview)

Comment: @TeachMeJava thats link is `end of scrolling in a ListView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(firstVisibleItem == 0 && !isFirstTime){
 //it is top of the list
}
```

define a variable in your class `isFirstTime` and initialize it to `true`. when the user scroll the list 
check

```
if (firstVisibleItem  != 0 )
{
    isFirstTime =false;
}
```

that means the user scrolls the list and the first element is disappear so if once again

```
firstVisibleItem  == 0
```

means the list scrolls up and finishs.

Comment: please try to include at least a short comment of what you've done and why :) it might help him understand thy why

Comment: Can you briefly explain your answer? Such small answers might get deleted in the future

Comment: @Bogdan Emil Mariesan is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

use 
OnSwipeTouchListener.java:

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        super.onTouch(view, motionEvent);
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    public void onSwipeRight() {}
    public void onSwipeLeft() {}
    public void onSwipeTop() {}
    public void onSwipeBottom() {}
}
```

USAGE:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {

    public void onSwipeTop() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeBottom() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

That might be helpful.I searched your problem on stackoverflow,and  I think this answer is exactly your question's answer. Scroll finish detect. 
[Click Here for Full Code Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358428/implementation-of-onscrolllistener-to-detect-the-end-of-scrolling-in-a-listview)

```
private void isScrollCompleted() {
    if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        /*** In this way I detect if there's been a scroll which has completed ***/
        /*** do the work! ***/
    }
}
```

Comment: @TechMeJava . how to resolve `currentVisibleItemCount` and `currentScrollState`? my Class extends `ListFragment`