# setOnScrollListener don't work correctly i don't know when the user is at the end of list

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onscrolllistener

I have a problem with scroll of my fragment.
I want load add another part of list, when the user arrives at the end of fragment.

Fragment one:

```
 View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
 list = (ListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list);
 ...
 MainActivity.Adapter adapter = new MainActivity.Adapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
 list.setOnScrollListener(adapter);
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

class Adapter:

```
public static class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
....
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This function don't work when i go at the end of page. Where is the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358428/implementation-of-onscrolllistener-to-detect-the-end-of-scrolling-in-a-listview

Comment: sorry don't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `RecyclerView` for the list and add the scroll listener on that.  You need to keep a reference to the layout manager on the recycler view.

```
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener recyclerViewOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        // don't load more unless actually scrolled
        if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) {
            return;
        }
        int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        // load more items depending on visible items and total

    }
};
```

Comment: what is mLayoutManager?

Comment: Should've been `layoutManager`. I updated.  That is the layout manager you use for the recyclerview when you set it up. The recyclerview set up code is not included in my answer.