# How to make an endless HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: java, android

I have HorizontalScrollView with Buttons inside and I want to add a new button every time my HorizontalScrollView reaches its end. But how to detect it?

Comment: add more details, what is that extra button for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6384609/2700586