# Show Button On Scrolling Down ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have added a `Button` at the bottom of screen. It is a "Go To Top" button.
I want to make it hidden when user is at top of the list i.e on first row, and show it when he scrolls down to beyond second row.

I can add onscroll listner to the ListView. But I am not sure how to check for row number

Can anyone provide an example how to achieve it?

Comment: You can try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123675/find-out-if-listview-is-scrolled-to-the-bottom

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451398/animate-hide-button-when-close-to-end-of-listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **setOnScrollListener**

> [**setOnScrollListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html)
>
> Set the listener that will receive notifications every time the list scrolls.

**sample code**

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            // add here your logic like this
            int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if (firstVisibleItem < 2) {

                fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else {
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Works fine after a little change.

`if (firstVisibleItem < 2)`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

[Find out if ListView is scrolled to the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123675/find-out-if-listview-is-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

```
private int preLast;
// Initialization stuff.
yourListView.setOnScrollListener(this);

// ... ... ...

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView lw, final int firstVisibleItem,
        final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount)
{

    switch(lw.getId()) 
    {
        case R.id.your_list_id:     

            // Make your calculation stuff here. You have all your
            // needed info from the parameters of this function.

            // Sample calculation to determine if the last 
            // item is fully visible.
            final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            if(lastItem == totalItemCount)
            {
                if(preLast!=lastItem)
                {
                    //to avoid multiple calls for last item
                    Log.d("Last", "Last");
                    preLast = lastItem;
                }
            }
    }
}
```