# How to show FloatingActionButton when the user reaches the bottom?

Tags: android, components, material-design

I'm using a FloatingActionButton in a CoordinatorLayout but unlike the normal behaviour I want to show it when the bottom is reached in order to allow the user to see more data.

To do so, I found on the Internet this Behavior for the component.

```
public class ScrollingFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
private int toolbarHeight;

public ScrollingFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super();
    this.toolbarHeight = Utils.getToolbarHeight(context);
}

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fab, View dependency) {
    return super.layoutDependsOn(parent, fab, dependency) || (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout);
}

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fab, View dependency) {
    boolean returnValue = super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, fab, dependency);
    if (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
            int fabBottomMargin = lp.bottomMargin;
            int distanceToScroll = fab.getHeight() + fabBottomMargin;
            float ratio = (float)dependency.getY()/(float)toolbarHeight;
            fab.setTranslationY(-distanceToScroll * ratio);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to do it. I have been playing with `fab.setTranslationY()` without success.

Anyone can show me any way to do it?

EDIT: I'm using mzgreen example: https://github.com/mzgreen/HideOnScrollExample

Comment: using this https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton ??

Comment: no, I was trying this code: https://github.com/mzgreen/HideOnScrollExample @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem using makovastar example (https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton).
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123675/find-out-if-listview-is-scrolled-to-the-bottom) answer pointed me to the solution.

There is a inner class inside [FloatingActionButton.java](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/melnykov/fab/FloatingActionButton.java) (FloatingActionButton#AbsListViewScrollDetectorImpl) that implements the scrolling methods.

Just add the following code to onScroll method:

```
if (view.getLastVisiblePosition() == view.getAdapter().getCount() -1 &&
                    view.getChildAt(view.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= view.getHeight()){
                //It is scrolled all the way down here so we show the button
                show();
            }
            else hide();
```

I hope it works!