# If we reach end of the listview, again i am trying scroll down to load more data. So how to give toast message to the user in android?

Tags: java, android

I am using recycler view in fragment. In adapter i am setting the data based on the position.
Once if i reach end of the listi mean last item. User is trying to scroll down ,then i have to display one toast message like there is no new feed . How to do it
?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your list item is last than show the toast

Comment: See if this helps:
[useful SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123675/find-out-if-listview-is-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Define `public static boolean reachedLastItem=false`
 In MainActivity's onCreate method write

```
if(reachedLastItem){
displaytoast;
reachedLastItem=false;
}
```

And in getView of adapter

```
if(index==getCount)
MainActivity.reachedLastItem=true;
```

Try this sample code. Please let me know in case of any help