# how to add OnScrollListener in my below code

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

It's been a while since I have been using android. can you please tell me how to add  `OnScrollListener`   in this code ? Everytime I scroll down I want to fetch 5 more images.

This is the `Asyncatask` its working correct, but I need fetch 5 image everytime I scroll down(load more).

```
public class RecyclerOkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private MyInterface mListener;
    public String category;
    public String basestart;
    public String limitend;
    public RecyclerOkHttpHandler(Context context, MyInterface mListener, String categ, String base, String limit){
        mContext = context;
        this.mListener  = mListener;
        category=categ;
        basestart=base;
        limitend=limit;
    }
    public interface MyInterface {
        public void myMethod(ArrayList result);
    }

    private final String Fetch_URL = "http://justedhak.com/old-files/Recyclerview_data.php";
    // ArrayList<Listitem> Listitem;
    ArrayList<CategoryList> Listitem;
    int resulta;

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    ListView list;
    String myJSON;
    JSONArray peoples = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("okhttp Fetch_URL", Fetch_URL);



        RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                .add("category", category)
                .add("base", basestart)
                .add("limit", limitend)
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(Fetch_URL)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();


        String result = null;
        try {
            Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            resulta = 1; //"Success
            //  return response.body().bytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Connection failed, check your connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        if( resulta ==1){
            myJSON=result;
            Log.e("result",result);

            showList();
        }
        else{
            Log.e("d","there is an error on postexecute in okhhttphandler.java");

        }
    }

    protected void showList(){
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
            System.out.println("Length:"+peoples.length());
            int J_length=peoples.length()-1;
            //JSONObject maxj  = peoples.getJSONObject(peoples.length() - 1);
            // max of arrray

            jsonObj= peoples.getJSONObject(J_length);

            String j_id=  jsonObj.getString("id");
            int _id = Integer.parseInt(j_id);
            System.out.println(j_id);

            //max of
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
            String db_id="";
            db_id = db.getmax();
            if (db_id== null)
            {
                db_id="0";
            }
            int d_id = Integer.parseInt(db_id);
            Log.e("db_id", db_id);
            Log.e("j_id",j_id);

            //  if (_id < d_id) {
            System.out.println("Getting json result ");

            Listitem = new ArrayList<CategoryList>();
            for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString("id");
                String url = c.getString("url");



                Listitem.add(new CategoryList(id, url));
            }

            if (mListener != null)
                mListener.myMethod(Listitem);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the when I set the adapter

```
 private String base = "0";
 private String limit = "5";

 final RecyclerOkHttpHandler handler = new RecyclerOkHttpHandler( this, new RecyclerOkHttpHandler.MyInterface() {
            @Override
            public void myMethod(ArrayList result) {
                mAdapter_first = new MyAdapter(result,SearchActivity.this);
                mAdapter_first.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRecyclerView_first.setAdapter(mAdapter_first);
            }
        },"girls jokes",base,limit);

        try {
             handler.execute().get();

        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.d("SearchActivity error", "error in mRecyclerView_first");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: does your endpoint support pagination?

Comment: @Blackbelt no it doesnt. just automatic load more

Comment: how do you ask for the next five then ?

Comment: @Blackbelt its a list view when i scoll down , it will automatic get 5 more images , in `base` and `limit` i specified 5 , in my select statement i added `limist 5` so in android everytime i scoll down i get more images

Comment: In your `AsyncTask`, you load all the data at once? Do you have a limiter in your php file response?

Comment: @RachikAbidi yes i  load all data at once with a limit , I have added a limit in my php. I want everytime to load 5 images eveytime i scroll dow

Comment: if you change the limit from 5 to 10, you will always get the old results as well

Comment: @Blackbelt true , but my problem not in the limit, I want to use `onscrolllistner`. I dont want when the app open to load all the 50 images, i want to load only 5 images, and everytime user scolldown i fetch 5 more did you understand what i want?

Comment: I do. You want pagination. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/bblackbelt/Fyber/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/fyber/presentation/view/fragments/OfferFragment.java)

Answer (score 0):

For the first load, call your `RecyclerOkHttpHandler` `AsyncTask`to get your first 5 items.

Now, for any further load, all you have to do is to check if the `listView` is scrolled to its bottom and you can refer to this link [Find out if ListView is scrolled to the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123675/find-out-if-listview-is-scrolled-to-the-bottom) to know how to deal with it.

So, each time you detect that the user has scrolled the listview to the bottom, it's time to call the `RecyclerOkHttpHandler` `AsynTask` to get the 5 new images.

**PS:** You need to save the limit you have reached in each load, so that in the next load, you start loading from that limit.

Hope this helps :)